# org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error updating 'CVE-2018-17481'

Tags: java, maven, owasp

I have upgraded the dependency-check-maven plugin version to 4.0.1 in my maven project and see below error when I run "mvn dependency-check:check" command. I suppressed this vulnerability and again tried:

```
mvn dependency-check:check
```

but the error persists.

> Failed to execute goal org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:4.0.1:check (default-cli) on project account: One or more exceptions occurred during dependency-check analysis: One or more exceptions occurred during dependency-check analysis
>
> [ERROR] org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error updating 'CVE-2018-17481'
> org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.nvdcve.DatabaseException: Error updating 'CVE-2018-17481'

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the org/owasp folder from your local maven repository.

Because the plugin's embedded database is located in this folder and it must be cleaned up after a version upgrade